# Defining negation

Tags: lo.logic, teaching

I'm currently coauthoring a book intended to teach first-year students basic proof techniques.  One of the chapters, written by my coauthor, is about basic logic.  In that chapter the negation of a statement is defined, and he says that he likes to think of $\neg P$ as the new sentence "$P$ is false".

Being familiar with Tarski's result on the undefinability of a truth predicate, I suggested that this new sentence doesn't properly belong to the original system, but instead belongs to a meta-system, as does any other statement which defines truth/falsity.  (Moreover, those statements are not the negation, because they are also restricted to speaking about a specific model of the theory.)  Admittedly, this is a subtle point (probably something we won't even tell our students about), but in talking with my coauthor I realized that I'm not entirely sure how we should then go about defining the negation, other than saying "not $P$".

So, here are my questions, which will hopefully shed light on this subject for me.

1. Unlike saying "$P$ is false", would it be okay to say "$P$ does not hold"?  Or is that also, implicitly, defining a truth predicate?  On the other hand, is it actually **okay** to define the negation as "$P$ is false" if we are speaking of falsity not as a predicate?
2. One of the problems with having a truth predicate would be the ability to create well-formed formulas of the form "I am a false statement."  Once we have a negation operation, what prevents us from creating a sentence which says "I am the negation of myself"?

Comment: I prefer negation is something that implies contradiction. So, instead of "P is false" I prefer "P implies false". For your second part, the liar paradox is not solely caused by negation. The sentence "If this sentence is true then X" is a self confirming sentence, always implying X. If X is false, then it is similar to negation.

Comment: For any sentence P, the negation of P is the weakest Q such that for all R, $P, Q \vdash R$.

Comment: Maybe useful : Neil Tennant, [Negation, Absurdity and Contrariety](http://u.osu.edu/tennant.9/files/2014/07/nac-2gav3mo.pdf) (2004).

Comment: Also Francesco Berto, [A Modality Called "Negation"](http://mind.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2015/06/03/mind.fzv026) (2015).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That second paper "A Modality Called "Negation"" was very interesting reading.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only problem with defining negation is that there are at least two notions of "negation":

Negation (let's call it $\lnot_1$) as a syntactic operation is quite clear: you prepend the symbol $\lnot$ to a formula.

Negation (or $\lnot_2$) is also a unary function on the two-element Boolean algebra $\{\top,\bot\}$  or $\{0,1\}$(but perhaps you want to use a different name for this operation, such as "complement").

If you want to give a "meaning" to a formula $P$, it is quite reasonable to say that the meaning is "$P$ is true"; then clearly the meaning of $\lnot P$ is "$P$ is false".

Teaching (or at least mentioning) the distinction between syntax and semantics, and also between language ($P$) and metalanguage ("$P$ is true") can be a source of confusion, but sooner or later students will realize that this is an important point.

Answer (score 6):

To directly answer your questions:

1. To say that a sentence "holds" is equivalent to saying that it is true, or that it is the case. You gain nothing by switching terminology.
2. You have to think about what you mean by "am" in "I am the negation of myself". If it means "I am literally identical to my own negation", we can indeed formulate a sentence S of first order arithmetic that asserts that the negation of the formula with Gödel number $n$ also has Gödel number $n$, where $n$ is the Gödel number of S itself. There's no contradiction here, as no string of characters is literally identical to the same string prefixed  with "$\neg$". So S is simply false, and would be for any value of $n$. If you want to say *I have the same truth value as my negation* then you need a truth predicate.

I strongly disagree with much of the accepted answer. "17 is a prime number" does not *mean* "`17 is a prime number' is true". The first is an assertion about a number, the second is an assertion about a syntactic string. We cannot assign meaning to a sentence S' by going to a metalanguage and saying that the meaning of S' is that S' is true. That idea is a non-starter, since that would only help if you already knew what the sentences of the metalanguage mean, and that leads to an infinite regression.

No, the way you explain what "17 is a prime number" means is by saying that it means that 17 has no factors besides 1 and itself. Truth doesn't come into this. To explain what "17 is not a prime number" means, I don't think you can do better than the constructivist definition, that it means "if 17 is a prime number then 0 = 1" (or whatever canonically false statement you want to use instead of "0 = 1").

Comment: +1, but regarding the last paragraph, to explain what "17 is not a prime number" means, why would you not say this means "17 has a factor besides 1 and itself"?

Comment: @SamHopkins sure, that's fine. I wanted a definition that could be adapted to any sentence, that's all.

Comment: (So for this particular sentence, I guess you could do better. I don't think you can do better that the constructivist definition in general.)

Comment: +1 for most of this answer, but one quibble — the wording “(…) is true” (or similar) gets used to mean several different things.  One of them is certainly as an assertion of a truth-predicate as you say, but another one is as the identity modal operator on sentences, where “P is true” is synonymous with “P”.  This and similar things are very useful for grammatical purposes — “…if properties (3) and (4) hold, then…” is much more readable than “…if (3) and (4), then…”  That said, I agree with your disagreement with the accepted answer: adding “…is true” doesn’t provide meaning to a statement.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine ... hmm ... It seems to me that "... if properties (3) and (4) hold, then ..." does use holding as a truth predicate. What about "... if every theorem of Peano arithmetic holds, then ..." --- is "holds" merely an identity modal operator here?  How would you eliminate it?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for uninformed amateur comment, however I believe negation is completely different from other logical operators. And of course this is just opinion but here are reasons:

1. Negation is single argument function, while logical convention usually works with 2 argument operators. When using Polish notation it is just onerous
2. Negation is an operator used in definition of consistency. Theory is not consistent if contain both p and ~p. This makes negation very special, rather closer to metatheory operator than ordinary logical operators. This content is at the same time booth syntactical and semantical
3. From explosion principle, syntactical consequences of 3 seems to be global, influencing semantical value of theory. No other operator has this power
4. It seems to be hard to replace negation with something else. While logical theory may be constructed around many two-argument functions ( in fact it even probably does not matter which ones) negation is always used, with no syntactical alternative.
5. composition of negation and quantification seems to be an operation gluing while UoD. Possible alternatives where ~"for every" == "there exists" are probably paradoxically constructs. Context is close to empty set elements existence here etc

Sorry for amateurish ramblings